# Adding ManytoManyField breaks Django

Tags: python, django

In my project, I have a model, Project, that when saved creates another model, Access, which contains a manytomanyfield, access_list, where users can add other users onto their project as collaborators. It works - when I create a new project, I can add additional users into it, but if I add a 2nd user, it will no longer serve the page with the error,

```
Exception Value: get() returned more than one Access -- it returned 2!"
```

If I switch to an account I've added to the project, then add other users on with that account, they add fine and it does not break the page.

When the page breaks, it also creates an additional instance of the project on my Projects page, even though there's only one instance of the project in the database.

My code:

Models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

    super(Project, self).save()
    Access.objects.get_or_create(project=self)

class Access(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    access_list = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required 
def access(request, project_id=1):
thisuser = request.user
if Access.objects.filter(Q(access_list=thisuser) | Q(project__created_by=thisuser), project__id=project_id).exists():
        accesspermission = Access.objects.filter(Q(access_list=thisuser) | Q(project__created_by=thisuser), project__id=project_id).order_by('-project__project_pubdate')[0]
    else:
        accesspermission = None
    if Entry.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).exists():
        anyentries = Entry.objects.filter(project_id=project_id, entry_unique=1).order_by('-entry_pubdate')[0]
    else:
        anyentries = None
    if Entry.objects.filter(project_id=project_id, entry_unique=1).exists():
        firstentry = Entry.objects.filter(project_id=project_id, entry_unique=1).order_by('-entry_pubdate')[0]
    else:
        firstentry = None
    if Entry.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).exists():
        lastentry = Entry.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).order_by('-entry_pubdate')[0]
        lastentrynumber = lastentry.entry_unique
    else:
        lastentrynumber = None
if request.method == "POST":    
    form = AddAccessForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        p = form.save(commit=False)

        adduserfromform = p.accessupdate
        if User.objects.filter(username=adduserfromform).exists():
            usertoadd = User.objects.get(username=adduserfromform)
            projecttoadd = Access.objects.filter(project__id=project_id).order_by('-project__project_pubdate')[0]
            projecttoadd.access_list.add(usertoadd)
        else:
            usertoadd = None

        removeuserfromform = p.accessremove
        if User.objects.filter(username=removeuserfromform).exists():
            usertoremove = User.objects.get(username=removeuserfromform)
            projecttoremove = Access.objects.filter(project__id=project_id).order_by('-project__project_pubdate')[0]
            projecttoremove.access_list.remove(usertoremove)
        else:
            usertoremove = None

        form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/projects/get/%s/access' % project_id)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/filmeditdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/webapps/filmeditdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/filmeditdb/filmeditdb/docproject/views.py", line 284, in access
    def access(request, project_id=1):
  File "/webapps/filmeditdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/filmeditdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 310, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num))
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Access -- it returned 2!
2014-03-25 22:48:26 [17264] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
2014-03-25 22:48:26 [17264] [INFO] SIGWINCH ignored. Not daemonized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a full traceback is generally recommeded, but from the error shown the issue is most likely on this line:

```
projecttoremove = Access.objects.get(project__id=project_id).order_by('-project__project_pubdate')[0]
```

Djangos [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) **always** expects to return **only** 1 object. If there is 0 objects, it throws a `DoesNotExist` exception if there is more than 0, it throws [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) Exception.

Change that line to match the earlier line here:

```
projecttoadd = Access.objects.filter(project__id=project_id).order_by('-project__project_pubdate')[0]
```

**Failing this, identify the erroneous call.** The exception you are getting is quite clear.
At some point in the code, you are calling `Access.objects.get()` with some parameters and it is finding 2 objects instead of 1. Either fix the parameters, or moer likely switch it to use `filter()`.

Comment: I swapped the line out but that doesn't seem to help. I added the traceback as you requested.

Comment: @JasonB I've added a clarification, but that line is the only call to `Access.objects.get()` in the sample shown. Identify the incorrect call to get and correct it to a filter or correct the parameters.

Comment: I don't have a single other Access.objects.get call in my entire views, I'm not sure where else or what else I can look at.

Comment: Well, if there are no other calls to `Access.objects.get()`, then by ellimination it *must* be that line.

Comment: I figured out this morning that the changes weren't being propagated because I wasn't restarting the server when I adjusted views.py. Now I'll make sure to restart it whenever I make a change to that level of functionality. Thanks!